# Why is GlassFish 4.1 slow on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, glassfish

I have a GlassFish 4.1 Server instance running on Ubuntu 15.04 Desktop Edition. I use this as a development server, where NetBeans will automatically deploy my packages as I work on them, for easy & fast testing.

However, there seems to be a major issue not present on Windows and Lubuntu which I also run GlassFish 4.1 on.

Whenever I use GlassFish4.1 any calls to the server via localhost or `127.0.0.1` result in wait times of up to 10 seconds for a response.

This seems to only happen during calls to dynamic content, i.e. not a static JSP page, but instead a call to a Servlet mapping, such as when a user enters form data and clicks on "proceed".

However, this problem is not present on Lubuntu or Windows.

I have checked my hosts file, which is setup with

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

I haven't been able to find the issue. I should add that the same Servlets, with the same code, and the same domain.xml runs perfectly fine on Windows and Lubuntu.

It would appear to be some kind of a DNS issue, but the fact that static JSP pages load perfectly fine makes me wonder if GlassFish is doing something behind the scenes with DNS lookups that is causing the slowdown.

Any ideas?

Comment: Random downvoters... Seriously?

Comment: Have you inspected network traffic to see if any DNS requests are being sent?

Comment: What about the second hit to the same jsp page? If it is already faster, then there is a problem with your jsp compiler. If it remains slow, then I would check first my jvm parameters.

Comment: Don't bother with random downvotes, it is a built-in random noise of the system. :-)